# If two operators say $D$ and $B$ commutes then why a non-degenerate eigenfunction of operator $D$ is also an eigenfunction of operator $B$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators, commutator, linear-algebra

I have following derivation which is not understandable for me and I am unable to understand it.Consider a eigenfunction-value equation $$D{\Psi}=d{\Psi}      $$
Now $B$ operates on above equation and gives$$BD{\Psi}=d(B{\Psi})      $$
since $d$ is a number. Furthermore, $B$ commutes with $D$, hence, we  can write above equation as $$D(B{\Psi})=d(B{\Psi})$$ above equation clearly shows that $B{\Psi}$ is a eigenfunction of operator D with same eigenvalue $d$.
HERE IS MY DOUBT IN STATEMENT 'since ${\Psi}$ is not degenerate with $B{\Psi}$ the eigenfunction $B{\Psi}$ must be a multiple of ${\Psi}$' i.e $$B{\Psi}=b{\Psi}$$ why this is necessary?
Explanation of this in my mind is since ${\Psi}$  and $B{\Psi}$ are  non-degenerate it must not give same eigenvalue,if above condition not met it is not possible to satisfy degeneracy of two eigen functions  . Is it can be written as following? $$D(B{\Psi})=db{\Psi}$$
my other question is if ${\Psi}$ is non degenerative then $B{\Psi}$ must be non degenerate?

Comment: oops! its degenerate .I quoted my doubt

Comment: The eigenvalue $d$ being "non degenerate" means that the eigenspace  of $D$ having eigenvalue $d$ is one dimensional. Since both $\psi$ and $B\psi$ have eigenvalue $d$ they are both in this one-dimensional space  and so coincide   up to a numerical factor. Note that it is the *eigenvalue* that is non-degenerate. The phrase that "$\psi$ is non degenerate with $B\psi$" is not really meaningful.

Comment: In my book there is nothing like eigen value being "non degenerate" its very confusing and yes what you said is right it makes no sense and I am making sense of non sense.Actually I have not studied linear algebra that is why I am very confused.

Comment: What book are you using?

Comment: BY IGNOU OPEN UNIVERSITY IN INDIA I AM DOING BSC (PHYSICS MAJOR)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider an operator $D$ with some eigenfunction $\Psi$ and eigenvalue $d$:
$$D\,\Psi = d\,\Psi \quad. $$

If there is an operator, $B$, which commutes with $D$, then it follows that (as you showed) $B\, \Psi$ is also an eigenfunction of $D$ with the same eigenvalue $d$.

If $d$ is non-degenerate, then there is by definition only one eigenfunction (up to a multiplicative constant) which fulfills $D\,\Psi = d\, \Psi$. Hence, we must have that $B\,\Psi = b \Psi$ for some constant $b$.

**Edit**: Regarding your comment. How do we conclude that necessarily $B\,\Psi \overset{!}{=}b\,\Psi$ for some constant $b$ holds? Let us take a step back and consider an operator $A$ with two possible eigenstates. It could be the case that
$$A \,\psi_1  = a\,\psi_1 $$ and $$A\,\psi_2 = a\,\psi_2 \quad .$$ Actually, it is easy to see that if we chose $\psi_2 \equiv c\,\psi_1$ for some constant $c$, then the second equation follows trivially from the first one. If this is not the case, i.e. if $\psi_2 \neq c\, \psi_1$ for any constant $c$, then we say that the eigenvalue $a$ of $A$ is degenerated.

Back to our example, where we have assumed that $d$ is **not** degenerated. According to our above considerations this means that we cannot have two functions $\psi_1$ and $\psi_2$ which would fulfill
$$ D \,\psi_1  = d\,\psi_1$$
and $$ D\,\psi_2 = d\,\psi_2  $$
while $\psi_2 \neq c\, \psi_1$. But we found two functions, namely $\Psi$ and $B\,\Psi$ which fulfilled these equations. Hence, since at the same time it cannot hold that $B\,\Psi \neq b\,\Psi$, we find
$$  B\,\Psi = b\,\Psi \quad .$$

Hope this helped.

Comment: The way it is described in my book is two eigenfunction degenerate its says nothing about d is non degenerate probably bad explaination in the book. Can you please clarify the last sentence this is what I am unable to understand why we must have that?

Comment: So you want to know why exactly we find $B\,\Psi = b \, \Psi$? I will edit the answer accordingly.

Comment: yes this is what I want to know

Comment: Let me know if it makes sense. However, also note the comment on your post, where mike stone also explained what it means for an eigenvalue to be degenerate. Note that my explanation is of course not the mathematical most rigorous one...